# Special character in Schema name in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I accidently created a schema in snowflake as `{"target_db.target_schema"}`. When I tried to drop this schema using
`drop schema "{"target_db.target_schema"}"`:

I am getting error as,

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'target_db'.
> Is there any way to drop the schema.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the "s? `drop schema "{\"target_db\".\"target_schema\"}"`

Comment: How was it created and also what do you see when you do show schemas?

Comment: It was created when I tried to pass database and schema from dbt project. But it did not take the variable value.

Comment: Tried to escape ". But it did not work.

Comment: Did you try the drop database from the web UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such scenario the Snowsight UI is helpful:

[image]

Under ellipsis there is an option "Place name in SQL":

[image]

Which returns properly quoted name: `TEST."{""target_db.target_schema""}"`

Comment: Thank you all. I could drop it from snowsight.

Answer (score 1):

You can double the double quotes:

```
drop schema "{""target_db.target_schema""}";
```